# getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution kubernetes + coredns

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

We have a service that sends tons of events in bulks. It basically opens multiple http POST connections.

Since we moved the service to kubernetes, we're `getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution` errors from time to time. (most calls work but some fail and it's weird.

Can anyone explain why and how to fix?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what calls fail? How are you addressing another service?

Comment: I'm making multiple calls to different domains outside the cluster (on the web). From time to time calls just fail. The errors in coredns logs are like: `<outside domain>.ec2.internal. AAAA: unreachable backend: read udp 10.0.158.199:51893->10.0.0.2:53: i/o timeout` - it's weird that coredns is trying to reach <outside domain>.ec2.internal and not just <outside domain>. Also, I don't understand why the timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Check the tinder post, they had a similar problem:

https://medium.com/tinder-engineering/tinders-move-to-kubernetes-cda2a6372f44

and the source for their dns info:

https://www.weave.works/blog/racy-conntrack-and-dns-lookup-timeouts

TLDR: check your arp tables cache gc_* host parameters, try to disable AAAA query in the containers /etc/gai.conf, move the DNS to a daemonset and inject the host IP as dns servers to the pods

Also, to help this and speed up dns resolve, add a ending dot to all domains (ie: database.example.com.), so coredns will try that query directly (one query, 2 with ipv6) instead of trying all the kubernetes search domain list ( about 5, 10 with ipv6). Only leave out that dot where you are querying for kubernetes resources or in apps that do not like it (if they exist, it's a bug, ALL DNS always end with a dot, while most of the time we can leave it out, with it is the correct way, must not fail)

Comment: Update, kubernetes 1.18  (when released) will allow a special  DNS in daemonset, so each node will have their own local dns that bypass the conntrack table, that will help a lot solving this kind of problems